# How to represent very specific business logic in classes containing the business logic?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

**BusinessModel**: I have a ice cream shop and I designed classes to do my supplier based financials based on industry types(Lines of business). I sell ice creams of many types, which I buy from different suppliers, and at the end of the month I try to reconcile my account by line of business using classes I created for cost calculation purposes. The method ProcessFile contains the algorithm specific to LOB calculation.

I am trying to think about a proper way to tackle this problem. However, I am running into a problem with naming classes and not exactly sure what design pattern perspective to use. I'd like a solution which is a engine - it gets input, does processing and produces an output.

Here is my interface to start with.

```
 public interface IFileProcessing
    {
    string InputFilePath { get; set;} 
    string OutputFilePath { get; set;}
    string ProcessedFilePath { get; set; }
    string ExtractionFieldsFromWebService{ get; set; }
    void ProcessFile(string FileName, string FilePath);
    }
```

All this is happening based on 5 different models(line of businesses), aka classes I defined. Lets say for example,  My classes handle my calculation of my costs

```
public class IceCreamLOB : IFileProcessing
public class FrozenCustardLOB : IFileProcessing
public class GelatoLOB: IFileProcessing
public class FrozenCustard: IFileProcessing
```

So far everything is generic to the line of businesses mentioned above. The complexity comes when I am being asked to design classes specifically for suppliers, aka example, BreyersLOB, or KlondikeLOB, which is say my biggest account and these accounts need special processing specifics.

I don't know if I should be naming my classes specific to supply vendors.

My questions are all related to this:

- How can I maintain logical processing specific to a supplier in a class without naming the class a specific vendor? Is there a good pattern when you come across a situation like this?
- How would I go about scaling this without using inheritance, or do I need to use it?
- What situations should name your classes specific to the vendor/business partner you work with? Like in my example, KlondikeLOB and BreyersLOB

Comment: Isn't that pretty much a textbook definition of the strategy pattern?

Comment: If naming is not the top concern, I am looking for guidance specifics, I can go about studying the pattern and see how I could apply them. I wanted to know what the immediate answer or first instinct would be when you encounter a situation like this. Plus the project is new, the .NET solution small for now and potential for growth is just starting to form.

Comment: I would suggest a good read of a book ["Design patterns: Elements of Resusable Object-Oriented software"](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0201633612?ref_=cm_sw_r_awd_HRByvb0B0EWSV) This book has real world problem and solution developed using design patterns.

Comment: A real company will usually do one of two things: 1) Negotiate to simplify the processing rules or 2) Maintain the processing rules independently of the application, then stuff them into the application as a custom invoice.  It's often easier to pay someone to do stuff like this than to try to automate it.  Yes, I realize this probably isn't a real-world project.

Comment: @Brain Can we not tag into your thought and develop a rules engine and apply all those rules to the custom invoice, and eventually cherry pick and choose the rules that apply to other vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could do with a bit more info on what process file is doing. But I think your problem may be in conflating the processing method with the line of business, or product type.

presumably we have some generic file processing methods, converting lines from whatever file format into product purchases or sales, then some processing working out financials on those purchases/sales.

I would split these two, into file processing, which would have input of file format X, say supplier specific csv and output purchase/sale records to a generic format/database.

eg

```
CSVFileProcessor : IFileProcessor
DATFileProcessor : IFileProcessor
KlondikeCustomFileProcessor :IFileProcessor
```

Then have ledger processing, which would have those records as input and output reports, invoices, payments whatever.

eg.

```
IceCreamProfits : ILedgerReport
KlondikeSales : IInvoiceCreator
```

You would record the supplier and lob in the ledger record, so your secondary process is able to only look at suppliers X or Y or lob A or B if required

Comment: I do see growth in the ProcessFile method. But you might have a point there to extract specific functionality into different interfaces. Hmmmm..

Comment: I might need to know more different answers and approaches as well.